# godaddy cert not working with filezilla

Tags: iis-7, certificate, windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate

here is what i have, running MS server 2008, IIS 7

from godaddy, a p7b intermediate file from godaddy and the cert in crt format.  this is all they gave me.  I need to get a private key file out of this to go with the crt and configure it to be used in filezilla.  i tried just loading the p7b file into the private key section of filezilla server and that didnt work, didnt think it would.  I have tried to extract the private key from the cert by creating a pfx file in the MMC then using openssl to extract the key using

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -nocerts -out key.key
```

this returns something showing that the Microsofot Local Key set has no value.

I am completely lost on how to get this work, have been trying for a few days.  Does anyone know how to get this to work with filezilla? Godaddy's support just doesnt seem to want to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is what i needed:

```
c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -nocerts –nodes  -passin pass:123 | openssl rsa -out privatekey.pem
```

this got me a private RSA key, which is then put into filezilla as the private key and the cert in the cert field in filezillas settings.  both of these files should be in a folder not protected by permissions and (not 100% sure on this part) should be in the same folder.

NOTE: this is after exporting private key from the MMC, this is the pfx file in question here, be sure the certificate is installed in IIS before doing this.